# Convert long to remaining time

Tags: java, timestamp

I'm currently trying to convert a long to a remaining time. I have got a

```
long remaining = XXXX
```

The long are the milliseconds to a certain date. For example: 3,600,000 should result in int weeks = 0, days = 0, hours = 1, minutes = 0, seconds = 0
how can I convert this long so that I end up with 5 ints:

```
int weeks;
int days;
int hours;
int minutes;
int seconds;
```

Thank you in advance!

DirtyDev

Comment: What does that long represent? The result of method `getTime()` from a date? Number of seconds/ms or another unit?

Comment: The long are the milliseconds to a certain date. For example: 3,600,000 should result in int weeks = 0, days = 0, hours = 1, minutes = 0, seconds = 0

Comment: Edited. Haven't tried anything, because so far, I don't get the logic behind how a method like this could work.

Comment: What part **1** calculate remaining time between to epoch **2** Convert a milliseconds number into time unit. This is just math. PS : I will not gave you the answer since this will not help you

Comment: So if it's just math, could you please tell me how I can use math in order to get my wanted result? Thanks :)

Comment: Division (/) and modulo (%) operator will do it. What is a minute compare to seconds ? What is an hour to minutes ? ... Just think. I will not help you more until you have post some code. Sorry ;)

Comment: Could `java.time.Duration` help you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I suggest defining the number of ms in a second, minute, hour, etc as constants

```
static final int SECOND = 1000;        // no. of ms in a second
static final int MINUTE = SECOND * 60; // no. of ms in a minute
static final int HOUR = MINUTE * 60;   // no. of ms in an hour
static final int DAY = HOUR * 24;      // no. of ms in a day
static final int WEEK = DAY * 7;       // no. of ms in a week
```

Then, you can use basic division (`/`) and modulus (`%`) operations to find what you need.

```
long remaining = XXXX;

int weeks   = (int)( remaining / WEEK);
int days    = (int)((remaining % WEEK) / DAY);
int hours   = (int)((remaining % DAY) / HOUR);
int minutes = (int)((remaining % HOUR) / MINUTE);
int seconds = (int)((remaining % MINUTE) / SECOND);
```

Comment: That will surely give him a good note on his homework but I doubt this will really help him.

Comment: This method throws an ArithmeticException, because sometimes it tries to divide by zero. The other answer works better

Comment: There are two typos in the answer: `remaining % hours` should be `remaining % hour`. `remaining % minutes` should be `remaining % minute`. Correct those, and it will never throw `ArithmeticException`. @DirtyDev

Comment: @DirtyDev, I had some typos. The code will never throw an exception

Answer (score 2):

Excuse me, I don’t want to criticize too much, still I gather from the other answers that it’s easy to either write code that is hard to read or code with typos that gives an incorrect result. DirtyDev, I am aware that you may not be allowed to use `Duration`, but for anyone else:

```
    long remaining = 3_600_000;

    Duration remainingTime = Duration.ofMillis(remaining);
    long days = remainingTime.toDays();
    remainingTime = remainingTime.minusDays(days);
    long weeks = days / 7;
    days %= 7; // or if you prefer, days = days % 7;
    long hours = remainingTime.toHours();
    remainingTime = remainingTime.minusHours(hours);
    long minutes = remainingTime.toMinutes();
    remainingTime = remainingTime.minusMinutes(minutes);
    long seconds = remainingTime.getSeconds();

    System.out.println("" + weeks + " weeks " + days + " days "
            + hours + " hours " + minutes + " minutes " + seconds + " seconds");
```

This prints:

```
0 weeks 0 days 1 hours 0 minutes 0 seconds
```

It’s not perfect, but I believe it’s both readable, correct and robust. `Duration` was meant for times from hours down to nanoseconds, so we still have to do the weeks “by hand”.

Happy New Year.

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want.

```
    long inputTimeInMilliseconds = 93800000;
    long milliseconds = inputTimeInMilliseconds % 1000;
    long seconds =  (inputTimeInMilliseconds / 1000) % 60 ;
    long minutes =  ((inputTimeInMilliseconds / (1000*60)) % 60);
    long hours   =  ((inputTimeInMilliseconds / (1000*60*60)) % 24);
    long days =  ((inputTimeInMilliseconds / (1000*60*60*24)) % 7);
    long weeks = (inputTimeInMilliseconds / (1000*60*60*24*7));

    String remainingTime = "time:"+weeks+":"+days+":"+ hours+":"+minutes+":"+seconds+":"+milliseconds;
    System.out.println(remainingTime);
```

Comment: I find the code in the other answer (Alexandru Severin) much more readable.